# How to mock a Nest service's dependencies?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I have a service in Nest that imports 7 other services and 1 Repository. I am trying to create unit tests on this service. Right now I just want to test if this service is defined to make sure my Jest is set up correctly.

This is the AppService I am trying to test. Eventually I want to test the `writeToProviderModel` method with a mock repository.

```
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectSentry() private readonly sentry: SentryService,
    @InjectRepository(HermesProviderEntity) private repository: Repository<HermesProviderEntity>,
    private readonly api: ApiService,
    private readonly cache: CacheService,
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
    private readonly ready: ReadyService,
    private readonly s3: S3Service,
    private readonly scheduler: SchedulerRegistry,
  ) {
    this.setupMasterCron();
    this.runPullProvider();
    this.setupCheckerCron();
  }

  //other methods.. 

  private setupCheckerCron(): void {
    const job = new CronJob('*/5 * * * *', async () => {
      if ((Date.now() - this.lastPullRunTime) / 1000 >= 300) {
        await this.api.resetLock();
        this.runPullProvider();
      }
    });
    this.scheduler.addCronJob('CHECKER_JOB', job);
    job.start();
  }
```

The current spec file looks like this:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { HermesProviderEntity } from './entities/provider.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ApiModule } from './api/api.module';
import { CacheModule } from './cache/cache.module';
import { ReadyModule } from './ready/ready.module';
import { S3Module } from './s3/s3.module';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

describe('AppService', () => {
  let controller: AppController;
  let service: AppService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [AppController],
      imports: [
        AppModule,
        ApiModule,
        CacheModule,
        ReadyModule,
        S3Module,
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([HermesProviderEntity]),
      ],
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AppService>(AppService);
    controller = module.get(AppController);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

I keep getting the error that CHECKER JOB already exist because both my test and actual module are adding jobs to the same cron job queue. I know I might have to mock all the dependency services including AppService itself and I am at a loss of how to even go about mocking them and the repository. I've tried following the example in the official Nest doc, chaining `.useMocker` to `.createTestingModule` but it tells me it's not a valid method.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: First of all, the high number of the dependencies of this service is a red flag about the single responsibility of this service. It means definitely like it is doing much too much and issues with tests which you are encountering are confirming that.
Try to refactor it and split it into smaller services with less responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

You can import a provider like `{ provide: SomeService, useValue: mock }` in your test module, and you definitely should.

Hitting live services in your test runs is going to cause significant slowdowns at best, and corrupt real data you care about at worst.

In your case, that might look something like this:

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
  controllers: [AppController],
  imports: [
    //... snipped ...
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    {
      provide: SchedulerRegistry,
      useValue: {
        addCronJob: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(someCronJob),
        //...
      }
    },
  ],
}).compile();
```

In my app, I created a helper function to make this easier:

```
/**
 * Mocks a service in a test application. The mock is typed to have methods that
 * conform to the interface of the service, or may be omitted if they
 * are unused in the test.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 *     app = await Test.createTestingModule({
 *       providers: [
 *         FooService,
 *         mockService(BarService),
 *         mockService(BazService, {
 *            doSomething: () => 'mocked return value'
 *         }
 *       ],
 *     }).compile()
 *
 */
export function mockService<T extends new (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>(
  module: T,
  mock: Partial<InstanceType<T>> = {},
): {
  provide: T
  useValue: Partial<InstanceType<T>>
} {
  return {
    provide: module,
    useValue: mock,
  }
}
```

Which comes in handy.